# QML: not able to see text on TextInput element of QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have created qml/test.qml file as:

```
import QtQuick 1.0
Rectangle
{
    id: pahe
    width: 200; height: 50
    color: "#55aaee"
    TextInput
    {
        id: editor
        anchors
        {
            left: parent.left; right: parent.right; leftMargin: 10; rightMargin: 10
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
        cursorVisible: true; 
        font.bold: true
        color: "#151515"; 
        selectionColor: "Green"
        focus: true
    }
}
```

and One qml/main.cpp file as:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtDeclarative>
#include <QDeclarativeView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.qml"));

    view.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);

    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I am compiling this main.cpp file using commands like:

```
#qmake -project
#qmake
#make
```

and I am running the exe as:

```
./qml
```

So problem is that I am not able to see any text on TextInput even after entering text using key board. If i print the TextInput.text of element it shows entered text on console log but can not see on screen.
What could be the reason?

If i run same test.qml file using qmlviewer it works fine.
Any hint or comment in this would be helpful.

Thanks,
KBalar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with virtual Linux machine running on Windows PC. So If i run same example on Real Linux machine The problem wont be there.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try simulator? U said, it as an exe and why r u running it in a Linux style "./". If you still have the problem, check the background of the Rectangle or TextEdit and  the font color.

Comment: I am running it on Linux. I have tried different back ground and different font colors. But still I have a problem.

Comment: Try to run is from Qt Creator itself. Like using Qt Simulator or by targetting Desktop.